# Ending TCP connection when no data is sent from equipment

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ethernet

For some background: We currently have a piece of equipment in house which we use to measure the height of an object. It will scan the object, compare it with a reference image and return a pattern match percentage, and if that percentage is above some specified threshold, it will take the height of the object. We use Non-Procedural Ethernet to connect to the sensor through a python socket, and the data is sent by the sensor. The code below showcases how I connect to the sensor:

```
import socket
import time
import pandas as pd

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
try:
    s.connect(("192.168.1.20", 8500))
    s.settimeout(30)
    data = []
    print('Recording data...')
    while True:
        msg = s.recv(496)
        d = msg.decode('utf-8').split(',')
        data.append(d)

finally:
    s.close()
    out = []
            out.append({'height': float(data[i][0]), 
                        'reference_pctg': float(data[i][1].split('\r')[0])
                        })
    csv = pd.DataFrame(data = out)
    csv.to_csv('./data/' + sheet + '.csv', index = False)
    print(csv)
```

Currently, the socket lasts 30 seconds, and is timed out after that. Issue is, we cannot use the controller to close the connection when the data is done being sent. Is there any way to set the socket to close when the sensor doesn't send any data for a specified time?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You've set a timeout, so then if there's no activity it should close?

Comment: Yes but I want to make it a bit more dynamic, as I have to wait for the socket to close to get the data, and I cant send anymore data unless its opened up again. The sensor is measuring a few thousand objects, over the course of a few hours. If its possible to automatically close the connection after 30 seconds of data not being sent, that'd be ideal.

Comment: What's happening at the moment? I see you're setting timeouts, does it not work?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your situation, but if you set socket option SO_LINGER to 0 prior to close, that will generally cause a reset to be immediately sent to abnormally terminate the connection immediately.

Comment: @Carlos I apologize, I was testing it out at a small scale and didnt fully understand how timeouts worked. When i implemented it with the machine running, the timeouts work exactly as planned, and will end the connection 10 seconds after the machine is finished.